# Obtener resulatdo de una tabla muchos a muchos

Tags: sql, oracle

Supongamos que tengo la sgtes tablas

"AGENT-DIVISION"

```
DIVISION_ID   AGENT_ID
102         1
104         1
102         50
4           100
```

"AGENT-ROLE"

```
ROLE_ID   AGENT_ID
2           1
4           1
2           50
4           50
4           100
```

Me gustaria obtener todos los divisiones que tienen como roles 2 y 4, en este ejemplo me devolveria las divisiones con id 102 y 104

He probado estas consultas :

```
select division_id, ar.role_id from agent_division d 
INNER JOIN agent a on d.agent_id = a.id 
inner join agent_role ar on ar.agent_id = a.id and ar.role_id in (2,4) 
group by division_id, ar.role_id 
having count(distinct ar.role_id) = 2;


select d.division_id, ar.role_id from agent_division d,  agent a,  agent_role ar 
where d.agent_id = a.id and ar.agent_id = a.id and ar.role_id in (2,4) 
group by d.division_id, ar.role_id having count(distinct ar.role_id) = 2;
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es agrupar por `agent_id` y mostrar solo los que tienen dos roles:

```
select agent_id
       from agent_role 
       where role_id in (2,4)
       group by agent_id
       having count(distinct role_id) = 2
```

Integrado a la consulta de `agent_division`, podrías ser:

```
select division_id
       from  agent_division
       where agent_id IN (select agent_id
                            from agent_role 
                            where role_id in (2,4)
                            group by agent_id
                            having count(distinct role_id) = 2)
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, funciona pero mi consulta es algo mas complicado al tener inner join, puedo modificar la pregunta o creo otra?

Comment: es decir, algo asi:
select division_id, ar.role_id from agent_division d INNER JOIN agent a on d.agent_id = a.id inner join agent_role ar on ar.agent_id = a.id and ar.role_id in (2,4) group by division_id, ar.role_id having count(distinct ar.role_id) = 2;

Comment: Según entendí, tu necesidad sería filtrar en una consulta más grande, aquellos agentes que tengan los dos roles. Si es esto, en realidad tu consulta base no debería cambiar mucho, lo único que deberías agregar es un filtro `WHERE agent_id IN (<la consulta que te pase en mi respuesta>)`, cualquier cosa agrega el código completo a tu pregunta y lo miro.

Comment: modifcada la pregunta, gracias

Comment: @sirdaiz, agregué la consulta que te decía.

Comment: muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho auqnue mi consulta es mas grande con esto ya me vale de ejemplo para hacerlo, q tengas un buen dia

Answer (score 0):

Como solo mencionas 2 `ROLE_ID` de tu interes; te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
WITH VW_VISTACONTEO AS (
   SELECT ROLE_ID, AGENT_ID, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTICION BY AGENT_ID) TOTAL FROM AGENT_ROLE WHERE ROLE_ID IN (2,4)
   GROUP BY ROLE_ID, AGENT_ID
)
SELECT 
   DISTINCT AGENT_ID 
FROM 
   AGENT_ROLE
WHERE
   (ROLE_ID, AGENT_ID) IN (SELECT ROLE_ID, AGENT_ID FROM VW_VISTACONTEO WHERE TOTAL>1)
```

Aplicamos a la "vista" creada en el `WITH` que devuelva aquellos repetidos mas de una vez (aunque lo correcto sería poner igual 2 de manera explicita), pero igual para que allí te sirva de guía..